# Understanding the mod rewrite [SMF forum] [Pretty URLs Mod]

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, module, friendly-url, pretty-urls

I have SMF installed in the root of my domains directory, with a portal acting as the front end of my website.

Portal = Home [mydomain.com]
SMF = Forum [mydomain.com/forum/]

The Portal creates custom pages which look like "index.php?page=page3457".

I am wondering if it's possible to rewrite the custom pages that are created, along with the forum URL using the Pretty URL mod for SMF.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# PRETTYURLS MOD BEGINS
# Pretty URLs SEO Pro mod
# https://www.smfhacks.com/prettyurls-seo-pro.php
# .htaccess file generated automatically on: December 29, 2022, 5:13

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rules for: actions
RewriteRule ^(agreement|acceptagreement|activate|admin|announce|attachapprove|buddy|calendar)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(clock|coppa|credits|deletemsg|dlattach|editpoll|editpoll2|findmember)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(groups|help|helpadmin|jsmodify|jsoption|likes|lock|lockvoting)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(login|login2|logintfa|logout|markasread|mergetopics|mlist|moderate)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(modifycat|movetopic|movetopic2|notifyannouncements|notifyboard|notifytopic|pm|post)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(post2|printpage|profile|quotefast|quickmod|quickmod2|recent|reminder)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(removepoll|removetopic2|reporttm|requestmembers|restoretopic|search|search2|sendactivation)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(signup|signup2|sitemaps|prettyurls|smstats|suggest|splittopics|stats)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(sticky|theme|trackip|about:unknown|unread|unreadreplies|uploadAttach|verificationcode)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(viewprofile|vote|viewquery|viewsmfile|who|\.xml|xmlhttp|forum)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: boards
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: topics
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*|msg[0-9]*|new)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.$3 [L,QSA]

# PRETTYURLS MOD ENDS

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Is it possible to create friendlier URLs for the custom pages and change the 'forum' extention to 'community'?

I have seen similar questions asked, with replies but I have limited knowlwege.

Comment: "_I have seen similar questions asked, with replies but I have limited knowlwege_" Please add links to those Q&A posts in your question post.

Comment: Is "the portal" something you have written or is this some kind of existing third party "portal" software? Is it related to SMF?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The portal is third-party, it's called 'TinyPortal'.

I've asked on their support forums, but they told me to ask the mod creator (which I have also done).

I don't understand how the mod rewrite functions.

Answer (score 0):

> ## PRETTYURLS MOD ENDS

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?page=page3457=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?page=page3457=$1

This makes the URL: /page/page3457/

Instead of: /index.php?page=page3457

Question is: Can it be changed so that it drops the first /page/ and uses a title instead?

So,

/url/

Not

/pages/url/

Basically, I am wondering how the mod rewrite code can be changed to alter the end results of the URLs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).